# How to understand Object.hasOwnProperty("constructor")

Tags: javascript

I'm a newer on JavaScript and have a question that confuses me a lot.

`Object.constructor` is a function, but `Object.hasOwnProperty("constructor") == false`.  Why?

As we know the prev of Object is null, maybe `Object.prototype.__proto__ == null`. How add the "constructor"'s property of object?

Comment: `Object` is a function. When doing `f = function () {}` there is no property 'constructor' on the Function itself. At least in Chrome, Function.__proto__ returns Empty, and Empty has a 'constructor' property (which explains the hasOwnProperty difference). I am not sure how this is codified in ECMAScript specifications.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.constructor` is not a function; `Object.prototype.constructor` *is*, and `Object` itself is a constructor. From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

> When called in a non-constructor context, Object behaves identically to new Object().

To see, try:

```
Object.hasOwnProperty("constructor") == false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("constructor") == true
typeof Object == "function"
typeof (new Object) == "object"
```

Comment: `typeof Object.constructor === "function"; // true`

Comment: The quote says `Object()` (ie. "..when *called*..") is equivalent to `new Object()`. But the *function* known as Object is not called in the question; with or without new.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Object.hasOwnProperty("constructor"), you are testing to see whether the property 'constructor' exists on Object. That is, you are NOT going to be looking up the __proto__ chain to see whether the property exists on the chain. For Object, the 'constructor' property does not exist on Object, it is an inherited property -> take a look at Object.__proto__.constructor and Object.__proto__.hasOwnProperty('constructor')

Note: Object.__proto__ === Function.prototype //=> true

Answer (score 0):

[image: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/]

Image taken from [Here](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/)

As we can see object does not have it's own property 'constructor', so whenever we do b.constructor, it goes to it's prototype and looks for constructor property in the prototype. but b.hasOwnProperty('constructor') would fail, but b.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor') will return true.